# Speed up Group By and count SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am counting/grouping about 1.3 million records with the statement below. The query works but is taking about a minute and a half, which is way too long for my application.

The goal is to get a one each (no duplicates) of the listed fields. The current query returns around 846 rows. I don't have any indexes so far, nor do I know much about adding them.

```
SELECT 
    [OfferId]
    ,[Name] 
    ,COUNT([Name]) AS 'Count'
    ,[Offer]
    ,[Title]
    ,[Text]
    ,[Amount]
    ,[Start]
    ,[End]
    ,[Image]
    ,[ImageText]
    ,[Type]
    ,[Disclaimer]
    ,[Link]
    ,[Status]
FROM 
    ClientDB.[dbo].[Offers]
GROUP BY 
    [OfferId]
    ,[Name]
    ,[Offer]
    ,[Title]
    ,[Text]
    ,[Amount]
    ,[Start]
    ,[End]
    ,[Image]
    ,[ImageText]
    ,[Type]
    ,[Disclaimer]
    ,[Link]
    ,[Status]
```

Table structure (not sure how to index this to make it faster):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Offers]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Company] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Property] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Account] [int] NULL,
    [OfferID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Offer] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [Text] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [AwardCode] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [Amount] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [Start] [datetime] NULL,
    [End] [datetime] NULL,
    [Image] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ImageText] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [Type] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CampaignTier] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Disclaimer] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Status] [nvarchar](100) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Offers] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: What indexes do you have on the table?

Comment: If possible maybe split up the query with limits and offsets, so you can show the user some of the results without getting all the results, maybe use pagination to go get more results depending on your application.

Comment: `[OfferId]` isn't the primary key?

Comment: It also might help if you describe the purpose of this query. Are you trying to find duplicates or something? I don't know your data, of course, but it seems odd that you are expecting to count records with all those fields the same.

Comment: How many rows are returned? 1,3 million rows might take some time... And what are you going to do with all those rows?

Comment: No indexes, I am trying to get a "one each" no duplicates from this table. I return 846 rows with this query.

Comment: If you add an index that matches the `group by` list, results should become very fast.

Comment: How do I add an index like this? And does it require dropping the table and losing the data?

Comment: This is easiest done from Management Studio (right-click the table, then Design). -- It does not require recreating the table (data will not be lost).

Comment: Will this have an effect on other queries I am running on this table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added indexes to the fields I was grouping together and this cut the time from a minute and a half to 1 second.

Comment: Knowing what indexes you added would help others, as would sharing the query plans (via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan)